# React Native Phone Oauth : App ID does not match requested project

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using React Native 16.3.0 with firebase 5.0.0
I want to sign in my users using the SMS phone auth.
I followed the tutorial mentioned in firebase documentation 
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/android

When I use the method

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber
```

I got the error

> Error: An internal error has occurred.
>       [ REJECTED_CREDENTIAL:App ID does not match requested project. ]

I am sure I am using the correct **google-services.json** file, but I cant
login ...

any advice..

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by getting the SHA1 key from my android production release key.. (not from the google play console).
I took the SHA1 from there and paste it in my firebase console screen, and now it is working

Answer (score 0):

1. You should **delete** `debug.keystore` in `~./android/debug.keystore` and in project `android/app/debug.keystore`
2. Create new keystore:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

3. **Copy** `~./android/debug.keystore` to project `android/app/`
4. Get SHA-1 and import firebase console like:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/55774552
5. Download `google-services.json` and replace in `android/app/google-services.json` and rebuild the project.