# Firebase PhoneAuth with Real phone Number Is Not Working But Whitelisted Number is Working - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am setting up Firebase Phone Auth in My App. I set up a Test Phone Number and a verification code in firebase auth section Whitelist. When I test with this Number and code, it's working. But When I Test With another number I got the Following error :

```
onVerificationFailed    com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException:
    The request contains malformed or mismatching credentials [ App ID does not match the requested project.
```

side note: I also use facebook account kit in this android app, and It goes well.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Please put ***SHA certificate fingerprint*** in your `firebase` account.

To get this `follow` these steps :

1.Open your project in Android Studio 
2.Click on `Gradle` Menu (From Right Side Panel )
3.Expand Your `Project` -> `Tasks` -> 'Android' -> Double click on `siginingReports`
4.You will see `SHA-1` and `MD5` fingerprint in your run tab 
5.Copy it and paste in your `firebase` console.

Comment: @NoorHossain If this answer helped you. then you should set this answer [as accepted.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/227624)

Comment: Also don't forget to Rebuild the project.

Answer (score 4):

Ah! (Alhamdulillah),  At last I have solved the problem this way :

What I have done wrong that, I have added the same android project and SHA key for Two Firebase Project.

The SHA key I have found for one app are Various according to build variant:

I got one SHA key, When I debug my app.
I got another SHA key, When I made release build for my app.
I got third SHA key for the Same app When I submitted this app in Play Console. (From App signing Section)

So, I have Deleted  My previous Firebase Project (because of no longer needed), And Create A new Firebase Project, Add this Android App and Add those All SHA key in Firebase :
**Project overview > settings > your apps > android apps > add SHA fingerprint** section.

And, Then its Worked Well. Alhamdulillah.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me :

1) Updated SHA1 certificate fingerprint for all package names (prod, dev..)

2) Downloaded `google-services.json` and added to `app/`

**3) Rebuild project**

It's the third step that I missed. It wasn't suggested in any of these suggested answers, so I'm leaving the tip here. Hope that helps some of you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should **delete** `debug.keystore` in `~./android/debug.keystore` and in project `android/app/debug.keystore`
2. Create new keystore:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

3. **Copy** `~./android/debug.keystore` to project `android/app/`
4. Get SHA-1 and import firebase console like:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/55774552
5. Download `google-services.json` and replace in `android/app/google-services.json` and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Google Play Console, click on your app after find **Setup->App Signing**. In **App signing key certificate** copy key in **SH-1** and upload to Project Setting Android in Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

delete your build folder and do invalidate/restart caches it will fix your issue 100%.

Comment: You need to provide more details in your answer. Just saying 'restart' it's not really an answer. You need to explain, what is the issue, why you need to restart, why your approach is better than other answers, what are problems if someone applies your approach, etc.