# Invalid credential: The request contains malformed or mismatching credentials [ App ID does not match requested project. ]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Previously I had used one demo firebase project for my android app, there the Phone based auth was working fine.
Now I'm trying to use a new firebase project instead of old one in my existed android app, but It gives me the following error.

The request contains malformed or mismatching credentials [ App ID does not match requested project. ]

com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The request contains malformed or mismatching credentials [ App ID does not match requested project. ]

I had removed the android app from old firebase project but it's not working.

Can someone please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

To use firebase Auth you have to put SHA certificate fingerprints in your firebase project.

Check this link to solve it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55774552/9972209