# Firebase OTP working fine on debug apk but not release apk

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I am using flutter and firebase OTP. The SMS is received while running the debug APK of my app.
However, I am getting this message while running the release APK using the command `flutter run --release`.

This is the returned message:

> This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please
> verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the
> Firebase Console. [ A safety_net_token was passed, but no matching
> SHA-256 was registered in the Firebase console. Please make sure that
> this application’s packageName/SHA256 pair is registered in the
> Firebase Console. ]

Kindly note that I am running this app directly on my phone and not by installing it from google play.

I tried the following on firebase console:

1. Debug keys
2. Release Keys
3. Google Play signing and upload keys certificates.
4. Also my google-services.json is up-to-date.
5. Flutter clean and pub get before running in order to make sure that the changes will occur.

I tried all the solutions presented by similar questions such as adding an email in firebase, adding google play keys, etc. and unfortunately none of them worked.

**Update**:
**Solved,**
**the problem was wrong naming inside the manifest file as the error message stated:

Please make sure that this application’s "packageName/SHA256" pair is registered in the Firebase Console.
Usually, it is the sha1 or sha256 keys, however this time it was the package name.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to generate SHA-1  for relase build and add it to the firebase console for the same project that you have registered.

Comment: You have to re download google-service.json file once after adding SHA1 for release build and try again

Comment: sorry man didn't work

Comment: did you replace with old google-services.json file ? and try to clean and run again to check

Comment: You should add SHA256 also

Comment: I added both sha1 and sha256 of debugging, release, and google play keys, yet somehow otp is still not functioning with real numbers (only testing numbers work)

Comment: did you replace your old .json file with new one ?

Comment: Please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62384384/firebase-phone-auth-not-working-in-apk-release-mode  or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55774387/firebase-phoneauth-with-real-phone-number-is-not-working-but-whitelisted-number

Comment: Thanks guys! it turned out to be the package name in the manifest file...

Answer (score 3):

1. do flutter clean and flutter pub get then.
2. use flutter fire cli to link the firebase project
3. Generate a signin report by doing cd android and .\gradlew signingReport
4. look for gradient release and upload that vairent sha1 and sha256 key.
   hope this sloves your problem.

Comment: Thank you! 
Also here is a guide for app signing: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#:~:text=Generate%20an%20upload%20key%20and%20keystore,-If%20you%20don&text=In%20the%20menu%20bar%2C%20click,store%20path%2C%20click%20Create%20new.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add SHA Keys in firebase console, to get SHA KEY

- Open Android Studio
- Open Project
- Reveal android folder
- Right click "gradlew" file and select Open in Terminal
- Go to the terminal view and paste: `gradlew signingReport`

You will find the SHA-1 fingerprint in the "Gradle Console"

Add this SHA-1 fingerprint in firebase console and test again

Comment: thanks but I already did this and still got nothing :')

Comment: Re download google-service.json and replace it in your android studio project?